# select value of active cell from a range

Tags: vba, cell

I have a range 'Bills' (A10:B50) containing dates of my bills, some are paid on the same date so there are duplicates and blanks at the end. I have a range 'Consolidated' (D10:E30) which consolidates the dates and bill amounts into single entries. When I click on the date in 'Consolidated' it highlights the individual entries in the Bills range using conditional formatting.
I use the following to get the date I am clicking on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Range("C40").Formula = "=" & Target.Address
End Sub
```

However, I use C40 elsewhere, it is formatted as a date, the vba causes havoc when the active cell is not a date. How do I get my vba to work ONLY if the active cell is within the Consolidate range?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row < Range("$D$10").Row Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column < Range("$D$10").Column Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row > Range("$D$30").Row Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column > Range("$D$30").Column Then Exit Sub

    ActiveSheet.Range("C40").Formula = "=" & Target.Address
End Sub
```

To explain, this checks the target row and columns and makes sure they are not below or above the range of your choice.  If you click anywhere outside of range D10 through D30, then nothing will happen with cell C40.

I have tested this and it works.  When clicking within D10 through D30, it changes the contents of C40.  Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Thanks John, works perfectly but of course if I click outside the range the previous value is left in C40, is there a way to clear C40 on entering the routine so that only a valid date gets into it, not the last one that was used.

Comment: I am assuming you meant @Busse and not John. There are multiple ways to do that. You can just add `range("C40").ClearContents` right before the if statements (or something similar to clear contents). Or `Range("C40").Value = ""`. I'm not at a PC so I cannot give the exact command.  

Either of those before the if statements will clear it out before checking if where you clicked is correct. If you want to only clear the contents after confirming they clicked within D10 through D30, then you would put it after the IF statements.

Comment: Sorry for getting the name wrong. Added that bit before the 'if', works perfectly. Unfortunately there are blank cells at the bottom of the ranges so I've put an 'if' in the conditional formatting statements to screen out blank cells being highlighted when C40 is empty. Thanks Busse for your help, last time I did any kind of Basic coding was in 1979!

Comment: Perfect! No problem about the name just wanted to make sure I wasnt replying without warrant. Do me a favor and Mark it the correct answer if it was correct and helped you. Glad it helped! :)

Comment: I have 12 worksheets, one for each month, is there a way I can add it to the workbook instead of having to update each sheet when I make a change?